# What is the probability of finding a certain gene of length $m$ inside our random DNA chain?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

DNA code is composed of a sequence of four nucleotides: adenine (A), cytosine (C), guanine (G) and thymine (T).

> Consider we have a random DNA chain (not closed) of length $M$. What is the probability of finding a certain gene of length $m$ inside our random DNA chain? Suppose $m<M$.
>
> We assume that the four nucleotides have the **same probability** to appear in every position of the chain independently.

My homework assignment is to solve the above general problem for $M=100$ and $m=2$, $m=3$

We can formulate the problem as follows

- our DNA chain is a M-tuple $S=(s_1, \ldots ,s_M)$ with $s_i$'s  chosen from the alphabet $\{ \text{ A, G, T, C } \}$
- And the gene is a m-tuple $T=(t_i, \ldots ,t_m)$

*My work*

*I know that there are $4^M$ different M-length DNA chains and for every one of them our gene could be located at the positions $1,2,\ldots, M-m-1$.*

*Moreover due to our assumption*

\begin{align}P(\{ \text{T is located at position } i\})&= \frac{1}{4^m} \implies\\ P(\{ \text{T is NOT located at position } i\})&= 1- \frac{1}{4^m}\end{align}

*But I have no idea how to proceed! Are the events  $\{ \text{T is NOT located at position } i\}$ independent  or not? Should I take into account the form of the gene?*

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: $P(\{$T appears at i $\})$ for various $i$ are not independent; and it depends on the actual pattern. Suppose $m=2$, and the pattern T is "AC". If T appears at position $i$, then T cannot also appear at position $i+1$; and vice-versa. On the other hand, if the pattern T is "AA", then if T appears at position $i$, it also appears at $i+1$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Also, note that the constraint "each of the **four nucleotides** has the same probabilitiy to appear at each location... independently" is not the same as the constraint "each **chain of length $m$** has the same probability to appear at each location... independently". You are asking for the former, but I think you mean the latter, which is much easier as a problem!

Comment: this stronger assumption cannot by made. consider a gene ATA, if ATA starts at  the first DNA base then for sure we could not find ATA starting from the second.

Comment: I found the same question, which has multiple good answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26988/102680

Comment: Unlike at that link, I give a complete solution for your problem with $M=100, m=3$, and any pattern with distinct nucleotides; the method can be easily adapted for all $M, m$ and patterns you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like the question "What is the probability of getting 5 heads in a row *at some point* when tossing a fair coin 100 times?". There's probably some niftier generating function approach; but here's my take...

Suppose $m = 3$. As we proceed along the string of nucleotides, we are transitioning from one trigram (3 character string) to another; for example if the string of nucleotides is:

$$AGCTACAACG...$$

we are looking at a sequence of $M-2$ trigrams (note that the last two characters of each trigram in the sequence are the same as the first two characters of the succeeding trigram):

$$AGC, GCT, CTA, TAC, ACA, CAA, AAC, ACG, ...$$

Suppose the pattern we seek is $ACG$. Then it must have preceded by one of the trigrams: $AAC, CAC, GAC, TAC$; and if we encounter one of those 4 trigrams, then in each case there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance that the next trigram will be $ACG$. This makes me think that we can model this as a Markov process.

So I think of this as there being 4 states: $ACG, xAC, xxA,$ and $xxx$ (for the last state, this is any trigram that does NOT end with "A", "AC", or "ACG"). Then the sequence of trigrams in the example I gave above is now the sequence of states:

$$xxx, xxx, xxA, xAC, xxA, xxA, xAC, ACG,...$$

The state transitions probabilities $P(\text{from state} | \text{to state})$ are:
$$P(xxx | xxx)=3/4, P(xxx | xxA)=1/4$$
$$P(xxA | xxx)=2/4, P(xxA | xxA)=1/4, P(xxA | xAC)=1/4$$
$$P(xAC | xxx)=2/4, P(xAC | xxA)=1/4, P(xAC | ACG)=1/4$$
$$P(ACG | ACG) = 1$$

with all omitted transitions above having $P=0$. $ACG$ is an absorbing state; and we will want to know the probability that our system enters state $ACG$ at some point during our stream of $M-2$ trigrams.

We can then define the transition matrix:

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and initial state probabilities for the starting trigram / state being $xxx, xxA, xAC,$ and $ACG$ :

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{43}{64} & \frac{16}{64} & \frac{4}{64} & \frac{1}{64}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So $P_4 = \frac{1}{64}$ is the probability for a sequence of length $3$ being in the state $ACG$; and in general if

$$P' = P \cdot T^{M-3}$$

Then $P'_4$ is the probability that a string of $M$ nucleotides contains $ACG$ at least once. In particular, for $M=100$, this equals $\approx  0.796888$, so roughly %80.

The above will hold for any trigram having distinct letters; but things are slightly different for patterns with duplicate letters.

Comment: I think your method is used when we make the assumption for our model that the the probability of a nucleotide to be appeared is dependent on the nucleotides appeared before. Moreover in order to use your approach the DNA chain should be known beforehand

Comment: Dang! That's less fun! :). The answer you accepted is not correct, BTW.

Comment: so the problem remains unsolved... take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827344/dna-sequence-probability

Comment: Wait - but I **AM** using the assumption that the probability of a **nucleotide** at step $i$ is independent of the nucleotides that have appeared before. That is why the sum of each row in the transition matrix is equal to 1; and why the elements of the matrix are multiples of 1/4! (I thought you were talking about the m-grams at first being independent).

Comment: Also, I should note that if M=4, m=3 and the pattern is "ACG", then it's fairly clear that there are 8 such strings that satisfy the requirements out of a possible $4^4$. However, if the pattern is "AAA" there are only 7 such strings. So it absolutely matters what the pattern is; so "the DNA chain should be known beforehand" is clearly required for a correct soluton.

Answer (score 0):

If all probabilities are independent, then the probability that the trigram at position $i$ is NOT a match is

$$\frac{4^m-1}{4^m}$$

and since they are independent, thus the probability that NONE of the trigrams match is

$$\prod_{i=1}^{M-m+1}\frac{4^m-1}{4^m} = \left(\frac{4^m-1}{4^m}\right)^{(M-m+1)}$$

And thus the probability that at least one of the trigrams match is

$$1-\left(\frac{4^m-1}{4^m}\right)^{(M-m+1)}$$

Comment: Not all probabilities are independent, just the probability of each nucleotide.  The probability that "CCCC" occurs at position 1 is not independent of the probability that "AAAA" occurs at position 2: those are mutually exclusive events.

Comment: I see from the comments above that you recognize this issue already.  But is it really solving a problem when you reinterpret the problem in a way that is self-contradictory?  It would be reasonable to have multiple different outcomes in this case, and no reason to consider any single one canonical.